# What does the bracket mean in this situation in React?

Tags: reactjs, input, setstate

This is a form component in React. I am wondering what does the bracket `[ ]` mean in that onChange event? Besides, I am a little confused that what does `e.target.name` equal to? Is that a string `"inputText"`?

```
<form onSubmit={(e) => {
 e.preventDefault();
 const data = [...this.state.inputText];
 this.setState({data, inputText: ''});
}}>
<input
  type="text"
  name="inputText"
  value={this.state.inputText}
  onChange={(e) => {
    this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value})
  }}
 />
</form>
```

Any comment or help will be appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Computed property names

It's one of new things in ES6.
It means that you can set `key` values for the object dynamically.

example:

```
// Computed property names (ES2015)
var prop = 'foo';
var o = {
  [prop]: 'hey',
  ['b' + 'ar']: 'there'
};
```

---

read more about it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it really helps!

Answer (score 0):

This is es6 syntax for using a string as a key. So, in this case this is equivalent to:

```
setState({inputText: <eventValue>});
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes exactly in this case `e.target.name` is equal to string `"inputText"`. So in `onChange` you can also think as

```
this.setState({["inputText"]: e.target.value})
```

equivalent to

```
this.setState({inputText: e.target.value})
```

This way generally used to create generic/reusable functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!